# What "module" takes care of assigning partitions to specific nodes, YARN/cluster manager or Spark itself?

Tags: apache-spark

Which module in Apache Spark takes care of assigning partitions to specific nodes in the cluster, i.e. which module takes care of keeping the mapping between a partition to a specific node? Is this done by YARN/Cluster Manager or this is managed by core spark itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this done by YARN/Cluster Manager or this is managed by core spark itself?

It's done as part of Spark Core's `TaskScheduler`, and more specifically `TaskSetManager` that [responds to resource offers](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/scheduler/TaskSetManager.scala#L438) (where resources are CPUs and RAM with CPUs being the only important scheduling factor).

Comment: Does the TaskSetManager keep an in memory map of partition to ip, I was looking for this in the source code but did not find a clear one

Comment: It does not have to. It's responsibility of TaskScheduler to assign a TaskSet for execution and once it gets scheduled we know enough resources are available for tasks (that TaskSetManager manages by exchanging messages).

Comment: So does the TaskScheduler take care of data locality aspects while scheduling partitions on specific nodes? Does it have knowledge of where the data is stored etc to do that?

Comment: Data locality is a (optional) feature of RDD and TaskScheduler does use it for scheduling tasks to executors closer to the data.